# Attempted import error: 'getMovies' is not exported from 'C:/Users/hp/vidly/src/fakeGenreService'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a very basic react app, i have one file name 'fakeMovieService.js'. Importing that file in movies.jsx which are in same folder.
There is a function in that getmovies() which basically gets all the value of movie stored in a variable and i'm trying to print that in  table created in movies.jsx.

But it shows an import error.
code in fakemovieService:-

```
    const movies = [
      {
        _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
        title: "Terminator",
        genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
   {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471821",
    title: "The Avengers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  }
];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}

 
Code in movies.jsx
class Movies extends Component {
    state = {
        movies: getMovies()
      };
    render() { 
        return <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <body>
                {
                    this.state.movies.map(movie =>(
                <tr>
                    <td>{movie.title}</td>
                    <td>{ movie.genre.name  }</td>
                    <td>{movie.numberInStorck }</td>
                    <td>{ movie.dailyRentalRate  }</td>
                </tr>
                    ))}
            </body>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need import the file like a relative importation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yes i did that, but the error is still there. what basically i have done is that i've imported getmovies() function from there and in state i have defined a tag 'movies' and i'm calling all the function using that tag with the help of arrow function.

Comment:  But in the `fakeGenreService` how you export the `getMovies`? Can you show the content of file?

Comment: export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}  where movies is the variable i have defined which has id, genre,title and 3-4 more elements

Comment: I see the code which you add, you don't need to export a function to get the movies.

You can just export the array, and import like you did.

Comment: check the code please
https://codesandbox.io/s/getmovies-ixct7?file=/src/App.js

If you want to use like a function, you need to execute on `componentDidMount`, and with the value, you update your state.

So the state will be start like an empty array

Comment: If i want to export getMovies function in state function, that is not possible? I saw your code but what if i want to export more than 2-3 arrays.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to use in react lifecycle, because could be a dynamic response:

https://codesandbox.io/s/getmovies-ixct7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Check the file you're trying to import, and verify that you're exporting the function as an object.

```
export { getMovies }
```

Please show the actual error you're receiving, as well as the file you're trying to import. A lot of time it's that the file doesn't actually export what you're thinking it does. :)

Comment: I've a variable defined cont movies=[] (It has id,title , genre...)  and an export function export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}

Comment: @TanishqBhatia Try removing the {} around your import. If you're not exporting in the format of an object, importing as an object will fail. So just do `import getMovies from ....`

Comment: Now this is the error i'm getting "Attempted import error: 'C:/Users/hp/vidly/src/fakeMovieService' does not contain a default export (imported as 'getMovies')."

Comment: @TanishqBhatia So now try `export default function getMovies ...`

Comment: It's not correct a function executing on state, you need to use the function in `componentDidMount`

Comment: It worked without componentDidMount , anyways thank you. :D

Answer (score -1):

I can see two possible problems, either you forgot to export or you are not importing it properly.
If you have forgotten to export, then you need to do that by using `export` keyword like this:

1. `export default getMovies;`

or

2. `export getMovies;`.

If you exported it as given in (1) then simply `import getMovies from '<relative_path_to_fakeMovieService>'`

If you exported as in (2) then `import { getMovies } from '<relative_path_to_fakeMovieService>'`

Remember to always use a relative path in imports for all languages and to post actual error with the question in StackOverflow.

Edit:
You are doing it wrong, please refer to the [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-pascal-c7qxh).

Comment: My error is the title of the post , sorry for the confusion and i've exported getmovies function - > export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
} where movies is the variable name in which there are array of values such as id, genre title and 3-4 more elements

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the contents of fakeMovieService.js ? or atleast getMovies ? you can hide the business logic inside the getMovies() if you wish not to disclose it.

Comment: Done. Its just a basic code, i dont mind showing it.